# Iterate with index using thymeleaf

Tags: html, spring, jsp, thymeleaf

I am new to thymeleaf and am converting all my jsp code to thymeleaf.I don't know how to convert this below code to thymeleaf.Do anyone know how to convert the below code to `thymeleaf`?

```
<logic:iterate id="id" property="idList" name="sampleForm" indexId="i">
    <label for="id<%=i%>">
      <bean:write name="id" property="id" />
    </label>
</logic:iterate>
```

Please tell me how to initialize the index value in `thymeleaf` to be used in some values??

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
<label th:each="id,status : ${idList}" th:for="|id${status.index}|" th:text="${id.id}"></label>
```

- `th:each` will iterate over the `idList`, assign each item to `id` and create a `label` for each item. The status of the item can be assigned by adding an extra name, separated by a comma (`status` in this example).
- `th:for` will set the `for` attribute of the label. The pipes (`|`) are used for easy string concatenation.
- `th:text` will set the inner text of the label to the ID.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use it like this:

```
<label th:each="id : ${idList}" th:for="${'id' + idStat.index}" th:text="{id.id}">
```

This starts the index from 0

If you want to start the index from 1 use this

```
<label th:each="id : ${idList}" th:for="${'id' + idStat.count}" th:text="{id.id}">
```

Check out the [Thymeleaf documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#keeping-iteration-status)